# Handle onSnapshot subscription in createAsyncThunk

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Currently i try to connect firebase / firestore to the redux store of my react-native project.

I've created a reducer with the createSlice function of @reduxjs/toolkit

```
const authSlide = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    authLoading: state => {
      state.isLoading = true;
    },
    hasError: (state, action: PayloadAction<Error>) => {
      state = { ...state, error: action.payload, isLoading: false };
    },
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addCase(setUserData.pending, (state, action) => {});
    builder.addCase(setUserData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {});
    builder.addCase(setUserData.rejected, (state, action) => {});
  }
})
```

in the action of the setUserData reducer i want to subscribe to changes in firestore, so every time a change occurs the state should be updated.

I tried it with this code and its working for once, but not for future updates

```
export const getUserDataById = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/getUserData',
  async (uid: string, { rejectWithValue }) =>
    new Promise<User>((resolve, reject) => {
      const unsubscribe = userRef.doc(uid).onSnapshot(
        snapshot => {
          const data = snapshot.data();
          if (snapshot.exists && data) {
            resolve({ uid, ...data });
          } else {
            reject({ name: 'Auth error', message: i18n.t('error.userNotFound') });
          }
        },
        error => reject(error),
      );
      listenerUnsubscribeList.push(unsubscribe);
    }),
);
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could solve the problem?

Comment: Firebase is not my area of expertise but you might want to look into the react-redux-firebase package.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've already looked at it, but I don't think the package works yet with the current version of react-native-firebase

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to create a separate component to listen (inside its useeffect) to Firestore changes and dispatch events to the store when something changes. Having a subscriber inside createasyncthunk doesn't seem right.

Comment: The problem is that there is nothing such as a "user" component. But the auth store should be available from everywhere in the app. Thats why i need to sync it with the global redux store

Comment: Ok. If I understand your requirement , you should set the user on auth slice. And then get it from auth slice across any component using selectors , am I right? This user you are setting is the current user who is using the app ? Or could be any user on app ? I see you are setting in auth slice, so I deduced as should be for currently authenticated user. 

If so, basically you want to listen for changes in firestore for currently authenticated user in your app ?

Comment: Correct, when the user register / login his account is create in firebase. At the same time there will be a node in firestore created for his userdata. This node should be fetched to my authState slice. When the data is changed the authState should automatically update, so i can use the data across the app.

Comment: Why don’t you crate a new AuthUser component and add this listener inside its useeffect. Then whenever firestore user changes , dispatch setuser. Add this AuthUser component within your Redux store component tree and return nothing but <View></View> from this component